# Add number in 001 format to file name in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, format, filenames

I upload a txt file to array and then I upload the array to a website, that downloads a file to a specific directory. The file name contains first ten letters of a array line. 
Problem: add number in 00n format before the file name. I tried several tips here but nothing works as I wished.
In txt file are random sentences like "Dog is barking"

```
def openFile():
with open('test0.txt','r') as f:
    content = f.read().splitlines()
    for line in content:
       line=line.strip()
       line=line.replace(' ','+')
       arr.append(line)
    return arr  

def openWeb()
 for line in arr:
    url="url"
    name = line.replace('+', '')[0:9]
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "dir"+"_"+name+".mp3")
```

so the output should look like

```
'001_nameoffirst' 
'002_nameofsecond'
```

Comment: Pls add the `arr` object to your question.

Comment: @Kasrâmvd you mean like this?

Comment: No, we need to know what's inside that iterable. Show the content of `arr` or at least some samples.

Comment: @Kasrâmvd random sentences, but just with words. No numbers can be used in sentence.

Comment: I don't get how your code relates to the question, but it sounds like you need to use a format string: `"{:03}_{}".format(23, "name")` evaluates to `"023_name"`

Comment: @zch now it renames those files but every renamed one has the same number but I need to iterate from 001 to 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using *enumerate* and *zfill* this can be done, also you can use the argument `start = 1` in combination with *enumerate*

```
l = ['nameoffirst', 'nameofsecond']
new_l = ['{}_'.format(str(idx).zfill(3))+ item for idx, item in enumerate(l, start = 1)]
```

Expanded loop:

```
new_l = [] 
for idx, item in enumerate(l, start = 1):
    new_l.append('{}_'.format(str(idx).zfill(3)) + item)
```

> ```
> ['001_nameoffirst', '002_nameofsecond']
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You could use string formatting and `zfill` to achieve the `00x` effect. I'm not sure what your data is, but this illustrates my point:

```
names = ['nameoffirst', 'nameofsecond']
for i, name in enumerate(names):
    form = '{}_{}'.format(str(i).zfill(3), name)
    print(form)  # or do whatever you
    # need with 'form'
```